# Devexpress ASPXGridView get column name from row and column indexes (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

In DevExpress ASPXGridView I want to get cell value by passing the column index and row index. I tried this.

```
Dim invNo As String
invNo = datagrid.GetRowValues(j, "InvoiceNo")
```

But here I need to pass the column name. In my scenario I know only the row and column indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a field name from the [ASPxGridView.Columns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_Columnstopic) collection.

```
datagrid.GetRowValues(j, CType(datagrid.Columns(colIndex), GridViewDataColumn).FieldName)
```